# Hard time with scripting in OpenVMS

Tags: openvms

I am having a very hard time with scripting in OpenVMS
I have a certain output in a file called test.txt .For example :

```
[WWEWE@http-lx-as code]$ cat test.txt
** Configuration for file "MULTINET:NETWORK_DEVICES.CONFIGURATION" **

Device                           Adapter   CSR Address  Flags/Vector

------                           -------   -----------  ------------

se0  (Shared VAX/VMS Ethernet)   -NONE-    -NONE-       -NONE-

s10  (Serial Line IP)            -NONE-    -NONE-       -NONE-

dn0  (IP over DECNet link)       -NONE-    -NONE-       -NONE-
```

I have written a script in Linux which helps to pick up all the information under the device column in this case se0,s10,dn0.
Can we do a similar thing in OPEN VMS

The Linux script is as follows :
SCRIPT :

```
for i in `cat test.txt 2>/dev/null |egrep '^[a-z]' |grep -v '\*\*' | awk '{print $1}'`
> do
>     echo Begin-interface: $i
> done
```

OUTPUT :

```
Begin-interface: se0
Begin-interface: s10
Begin-interface: dn0
```

Let me know if it can be achieved,
Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you need anything in the first column below the line starting with '-'
you can try the following in a command file, e.g. extract_if.com

```
$    IF P1 .EQS. "" THEN GOTO nothing_specified
$    IF F$SEARCH( P1 ) .EQS. "" THEN GOTO file_not_found
$    parse_line = 0
$    OPEN/READ/ERROR=file_open_error infile 'P1'
$read_loop:
$    READ/ERROR=file_read_error/END_OF_FILE=end_of_file infile inline
$    IF F$LENGTH( F$EDIT( inline, "TRIM" ) ) .EQ. 0 THEN GOTO read_loop
$    IF parse_line .EQ. 1
$    THEN
$        interface = F$ELEMENT( 0, " ", F$EDIT( inline, "TRIM,COMPRESS" ) )
$        WRITE SYS$OUTPUT F$FAO( "Begin-interface: !AS", interface )
$    ELSE
$        parse_line = ( F$EXTRACT( 0,1,inline ) .EQS. "-" )
$    ENDIF
$    GOTO read_loop
$nothing_specified:
$    WRITE SYS$OUTPUT "No file specified"
$    GOTO finished
$file_not_found:
$    WRITE SYS$OUTPUT F$FAO( "File !AS not found", P1 )
$    GOTO finished
$file_open_error:
$    WRITE SYS$OUTPUT F$FAO( "Error opening file !AS", P1 )
$    GOTO finished
$file_read_error:
$    WRITE SYS$OUTPUT F$FAO( "Error reading from file !AS", P1 )
$    GOTO close_file
$end_of_file:
$close_file:
$    IF F$TRNLNM("infile").NES."" THEN CLOSE infile
$finished:
$    EXIT
```

Run this script using:

```
$ @extract_if test.txt
```

The output should be as specified.

It seems you are familiar with AWK. You can also install GAWK for OpenVMS.

Comment: Thank you for your comments .But is there a way i can execute it directly on the command line rather than creating a script and running it.

Comment: @Ziax, You wrote a script in Linux, but you don't want to write a script for VMS??  I don't understand.

Comment: @Ziax why would you want that. The whole idea of scripting is not having to type it over and over again. Obviously, after the command script has been created, you can execute it directly from the command line. In this case, you enter and the command line `code`@extract_if test.txt `code`
How much simpler should it be. Mind you, OpenVMS is in no way Linux.

Another option would be to install GNV. Have a look at that on the HP website. IMHO that is especially for those who don't understand the  power of OpenVMS DCL.

Answer (score 1):

Two years late....

```
$ gawk/comm="/^[a-z]/{print ""Begin-interface:"",$1}" test.tmp
Begin-interface: se0
Begin-interface: s10
Begin-interface: dn0
```

Guess I will never understand those Unix script weenies which think they need 4 or 5 piped commands, then the proper tool and do everything in one step.

Piping 'cat' output into awk or perl is the most obvious and obnoxious sign of clueless-ness.
Oh well... Onwards!
Hein.

Comment: What a Heiny ;)